Deriving the normal equations by differentiating the matrix form
So, if we have $RSS(\beta) = (\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\beta)^T(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\beta)$ and differentiatiate with respect to $\beta$, and set it to zero in order to minimize it, how do we get $\mathbf{X}^T(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\beta)=0$?
What I got is $\mathbf{X}^T(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\beta)+(\mathbf{X}^T(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\beta))^T=0$
And that is the same only if the transpose of $\mathbf{X}^T(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\beta)$ is the same as itself... that means that $\mathbf{X}^T(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\beta)$ must be symmetric.
But, why is that so? I know this is a basic question that have come up a lot here, but i think there is a sort of a leap between calculus based statistics and using linear algebra. I've had some linear algebra, but still I cannot solve this... that focused more on spaces and projections and orthogonality, not differentiating matrices...
But, how can it even be symmetric? Because it's a p x 1 vector and not even square... my result doesn't make any sense.

How did you get what you got?

I just differentiated using the chain rule, and got $\mathbf{-X}^T(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\beta)-(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\beta)^T\mathbf{X}$...

See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=matrix+derivative+is%3Aanswer+score%3A5  Potentially helpful for the issue of the "leap" is https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/257579. For details, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46151 does a good job of laying out the calculations.

@whuber thanks, and this was helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/189434/derivative-of-quadratic-form , the #1 answer at least... it's a quadratic form, or scalar 1x1, so its automatically symmetrical. The $\beta^T A \beta$

Be careful: being scalar does not imply symmetry.  I provide an explicit demonstration of the symmetry at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/321768/919, for instance.
